# C, Every word in new line

Tags: c

Task is 'write a program in C that puts very word from input in new line without using strings'. I have tried to solve it by doing this but i never get any response (not even with a single letter). I have tried too seek help on other tasks but they usually solve it with string. As i am new to C my beginner course still works only with char and not with string. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        int c;
        int state;
        state=1;
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
            if(c=' ')
                 state=0;
            else 
                if (state=0) {
                    putchar('\n');
                    state=1; }
                    else putchar(c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (c == ' ')` (and `if (state == 0)`) rather than assignment. BTW: turn on all your compiler warnings it will help you.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems in your code

- `if(c=' ')` where = must be ==
- `if (state=0)` where = must be ==
- the character after a space is lost and replaced by a \n
- characters like \n are not considered as a space

The function *isspace* is your friend to know if a character has the role of a space.

A proposal to correct all the problems can be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
  int c;
  int inWord = 0;

  while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
    if (!isspace(c)) {
      putchar(c);
      inWord = 1;
    }
    else if (inWord) {
      putchar('\n');
      inWord = 0;
    }
  }

  if (inWord)
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra -g s.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat f
just    a
 test of  
validity
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out < f
just
a
test
of
validity
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was using pascal in my last semester so a huge mistake like that missed my radar. Also i succeeded in resolving the issue just by adding another putchar(c); below putchar(\n) so that character isn't lost. Now i am going to work my way into making the program see things such as new line and \t as spaces without a function (just for learning purposes). Thank you again and have a nice day. :)